# Databinding controls to properties of ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to have a WPF window with a `ComboBox`, with which you select an item, and then use `TextBoxes` below to edit the properties of the currently selected item, eg `Name` and `Age`.

How do I do this with Data Binding, ie. to bind the name `TextBox` to the `Name` property of the currently selected item in the `ComboBox`?

My XAML is

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest001.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=CURR.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=CURR.Age, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MO}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CURR, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Name="MyComboBox"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where my code behind is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<myObj> mo;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mo = new ObservableCollection<myObj>();
        mo.Add(new myObj("Test1", 2));
        var ct  =  new MainWindowDatacontext(this);
        this.DataContext = ct;
        this.MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private class MainWindowDatacontext : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        MainWindow parent;
        myObj curr;
        public MainWindowDatacontext(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            this.parent = mainWindow;
        }
        public ObservableCollection<myObj> MO
        {
            get
            {
                return parent.mo;
            }
        }
        public myObj CURR
        {
            get
            {
                return curr;
            }
            set
            {
                this.curr = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void executePropertyChanged(string s)
        {

            if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this.parent, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mo.Add(new myObj("Test2", 10));
    }
}
```

But the Data Binding only works for the `ComboBox`- the `TextBoxes` never bind to anything.

`myObj` is very simple:

```
public class myObj : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void propertyChanged(string s)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
        }
    }


    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set {
            name = value;
            propertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    int age;


    public myObj(string p1, int p2)
    {
        this.name = p1;
        this.age = p2;
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value;
        propertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}", name, age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you receive an error in your output console during debugging?

Comment: No- there is no output on window load or when I select an element in the combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to bind to the property of another element in your application you should use [`Binding.ElementName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx) Property. So Change your `TextBox`'s `Binding` like this:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=MyComboBox, 
               Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Age, ElementName=MyComboBox,
               Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) in your ComboBox rather than [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx).

The former is for when you want to select one property out of the object in the ComboBox's ItemsSource rather than the object itself. It's used in conjunction with the [`SelectedValuePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx).

As you want to edit more than one property of the selected item you need to use `SelectedItem`.